# Salvar e carregar objetos dentro de uma list

Tags: java, lista

Olá, alguém pode me dizer porque só está carregando o value, e a key está em branco/nulo?

Código que eu uso pra salvar e carregar:

```
        public static List<Pair<String, String>> cash_player = new ArrayList<>();
        public static void save() {
        File f = new File(plugin().getDataFolder(), "cash.dat");
        if (!(f.exists()))
            try {
                f.createNewFile();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        try {
            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(f));
            oos.writeObject(cash_player);
            oos.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static void load() {
        File f = new File(Main.m.getDataFolder(), "cash.dat");
        if (f.exists()) {
            try {
                ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(f));
                cash_player = (List<Pair<String, String>>) ois.readObject();
                ois.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }
        }
    }`
```

Classe `Pair`:

```
class Pair<K, V> implements Serializable{
/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 6014244905733911500L;
K key;
  V value;

  public Pair(K key, V value) {
    this.key = key;
    this.value = value;
  }

}
```

Como eu uso para pegar o `key` e o `value`:

```
Cash.cash_player.get(0).value; // Retorna o valor salvo no objeto :D 
Cash.cash_player.get(0).key; // Retorna o nada =[
```

Isso é como se não tivesse salvando por completo.

Comment: Por que você não usa um HashMap?

Comment: Da esse erro Incorrect number of arguments for type HashMap<K,V>; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <Pair<String,String>>

public static HashMap<Pair<String, String>> quiz = new HashMap<>;

Comment: Ah tah, mas aí vc tem que salvar o objeto como HashMap também

Comment: Não entendi.

Coloquei assim

`public static HashMap<Pair<String, String>> quiz = new HashMap<Pair<String, String>>();`

Comment: Não, você tem que utilizar HashMap<String, String> = new HashMap<String, String>

Comment: Se você usar o hashmap, como sugerido, você não precisa mais usar a classe pair.

Answer (score 4):

Faça assim:

```
public static Map<String, String> cash_player = new HashMap<>();

public static synchronized void save() {
    File f = new File(plugin().getDataFolder(), "cash.dat");
    if (!(f.exists())) {
        try {
            f.createNewFile();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    try (ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(f))) {
        oos.writeObject(cash_player);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static synchronized void load() {
    File f = new File(Main.m.getDataFolder(), "cash.dat");
    if (f.exists()) {
        try (ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(f))) {
            cash_player = (Map<String, String>) ois.readObject();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

E com isso você pode jogar fora a sua classe `Pair`.

Observe também o uso do *try-with-resources* e do *synchronized*.

Comment: Esse *try-with-resources* chama o `close()` no `finally`?

Comment: @jbueno Sim. Nessa sintaxe do `try (...) { ... }` (note os parênteses), o compilador acrescenta automaticamente, por debaixo dos panos, um bloco `finally` que invoca o `close();` e lida com as exceções correspondentes usando o mecanismo de *suppressed exceptions*. Tudo isso foi acrescentado na linguagem no Java 7.

Comment: Legal, obrigado pela explicação.

Comment: Rapaz, estava eu tinha deixado a string nulla no código, por isso que retornava nada, desculpe, muita falta de atenção minha.

Comment: @Luiz se a resposta ajudou na solução do teu problema podes marcar como aceite. Se não responde tu, mas com código e explicação onde estava a falha e como corrigiste isso.